# Python/R: Matching list of strings with other list of strings

Tags: python, r

I need to extract a subset of IDs (strings) from a complete dataset with more than 4000 IDs. I have my list of IDs (eg. 'NDR895', 'NDR361',...) that I need from the bigger dataset saved as dataframe (or list), and the IDs in the bigger dataset are slightly different (eg. 'sb-NDR895_T1', 'sb-NDR361_T1',...). I tried it with `grepl()` and `regex()` but both options don't really work, because the strings are different.
Does anyone know how I could fix this using python or R?
In R, I tried something like this:

```
match <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(ID1$ID)) {
match = as.data.frame(rbind(match, grep(I, ID2$ID, value = T)))
}
```

But this doesn't work!?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @maduba, were you able to solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

## In R:

You can use `grepl()` to find a pattern in a string:

```
a <- "NDR895"
b <- "NDR361"

ids <- c("sb-NDR895_T1", "sb-NDR361_T1")

grepl(a, x = ids)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
grepl(b, x = ids)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

You could define a pattern based on your target strings, where `|` means 'or':

```
targets <- c(a, b)

pattern <- paste(targets, collapse = "|")
pattern
#> [1] "NDR895|NDR361"

grepl(pattern, ids)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
```

General example of using this approach to subset a dataframe:

```
df[grepl(pattern, df$ids),]
```